# Specific way to show a serie in MSChart using c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-visualization, mschart

I wonder if there is any way to show this serie as follows, the chartype is column.

[image: The Chart]

I'm aware that I need an (X,Y) pair to show the datapoint in the graph, but the thing is that I need to show a Y value in a range of x, to clarify this, let's put an example:

The X axis shows the hours and Y axis production values, in this case the production started at 7:30, so from 7:30 to 8 the production was let's say 20 units; from 8-9, 60 units; 9-10, 45 units and from 10-10:35 18 units.

Can I accomplish that with MSChart, or perhaps any other one that you guys suggest me? This is a winform app.

Thanks

Comment: Check this out, it may be able to help if modified to what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624066/how-to-set-values-in-x-axis-mschart-using-c

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the [MS Chart site](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart). The Downloads tab has WinForms examples that you can download as a WinForms project, run in Visual Studio, and view the code for the chart you want. The Chart controls are included with .Net 4, but can be downloaded and added as a reference for .Net 3.5.

What you want is a Column chart. You set the values as a series on the chart, and then you can pick the width of the column to show the range of x-values you want.

The basic idea is you create a `Chart`, `ChartArea`, and `Series`, and optionally a `Title` and `Legend`.

You add one or more `Series` objects to the `ChartArea`, then add the `ChartArea`, `Title`, and `Legend` to the `Chart`.

You add `DataPoints` individually to the `Series`, as in the example below, or you set the `Chart.DataSource` to something like a `DataTable` and use `DataBinding`.

Here's a snippet from the Column Chart example:

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend legend1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend();
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint dataPoint1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint(36890, 32);
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint dataPoint2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint(36891, 56);
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint dataPoint3 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint(36892, 35);
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint dataPoint4 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint(36893, 12);
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint dataPoint5 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint(36894, 35);
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint dataPoint6 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint(36895, 6);
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint dataPoint7 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint(36896, 23);
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Title title1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Title();

chart1.BackGradientStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.GradientStyle.TopBottom;
chart1.BorderlineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Solid;
chart1.BorderlineWidth = 2;
chart1.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;

chartArea1.Area3DStyle.Inclination = 15;
chartArea1.Area3DStyle.IsClustered = true;
chartArea1.Area3DStyle.IsRightAngleAxes = false;
chartArea1.Area3DStyle.Perspective = 10;
chartArea1.Area3DStyle.Rotation = 10;
chartArea1.Area3DStyle.WallWidth = 0;
chartArea1.AxisX.LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize = 8;
chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MM-dd";
chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = false;
chartArea1.AxisX.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
chartArea1.AxisY.LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize = 8;
chartArea1.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
chartArea1.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "C0";
chartArea1.AxisY.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
chartArea1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.OldLace;
chartArea1.BackGradientStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.GradientStyle.TopBottom;
chartArea1.BackSecondaryColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
chartArea1.Name = "Default";
chartArea1.ShadowColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;

chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);

legend1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
legend1.Enabled = false;
legend1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
legend1.IsTextAutoFit = false;
legend1.Name = "Default";

chart1.Legends.Add(legend1);
chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 64);
chart1.Name = "chart1";

series1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(180)))), ((int)(((byte)(26)))), ((int)(((byte)(59)))), ((int)(((byte)(105)))));
series1.ChartArea = "Default";
series1.Legend = "Default";
series1.Name = "Series1";
series1.Points.Add(dataPoint1);
series1.Points.Add(dataPoint2);
series1.Points.Add(dataPoint3);
series1.Points.Add(dataPoint4);
series1.Points.Add(dataPoint5);
series1.Points.Add(dataPoint6);
series1.Points.Add(dataPoint7);
series1.XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.DateTime;

chart1.Series.Add(series1);
chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(412, 296);
chart1.TabIndex = 0;

title1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
title1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(26)))), ((int)(((byte)(59)))), ((int)(((byte)(105)))));
title1.Name = "Title1";
title1.ShadowColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(32)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
title1.ShadowOffset = 3;
title1.Text = "Column Chart";

chart1.Titles.Add(title1);
```

Comment: thanks for your respond @nekno, but I think that won't work for me. As you can notice in your sample, series1.Points.Add(dataPoint1) where dataPoint1 is a pair X,Y; will draw a column (because the CharType is column) in that point, it's the same if you do this: series1.Points.AddXY(8,20). What I need is this: series1.Points.AddXY({7.30,8},20) but such a thing is not supported. Anyway I'll give you a vote because it's a good sample of how to work with MSchart.