# Windows Charts Forms C# Auto labeling of the points on X

Tags: c#, windows, forms, charts

I'm having some issues with Windows charts and the points displayed on the x-axis.

I have two plots of data in a line chart based upon set data points, e.g. 200,400,600,800,1000. I also use a 3rd & 4th series to colour areas depending which line is higher. To do this I've had to add extra points where the two lines intersect. This then throws out the labels on the x axis as the chart automatically labels the points something odd such as:

|
|
|
|

=========================
   120......370.....590.....730......850

Is there a way I can explicitly specify the datapoints on the axis that I want to use, other than the min-maximum value function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to customize the X axis labels to match your data? If so you can define custom labels and a customize event to do that. This was posted on StackOverflow by the user Somebody

[How to set values in x axis MSChart using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624066/how-to-set-values-in-x-axis-mschart-using-c-sharp)

Comment: That's a lot easier than I thought.