# Plot hours and minutes Y axis on vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, plot

I want to plot a graph where in the X axis should appear the name of some production lines, and in the Y axis the total time the lines were stopped (E.G: 110:43:00h) but i'm having some problems.
Here's my code:

```vb
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
Chart2.Series.Add("Stops")
Try
    ConnectDatabase()
    With cmd
        .Connection = conn
        .CommandText = "SELECT X as lines, time_format(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(abs(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(Y, Z))))),'%H:%i:%s') AS SUM FROM M, N WHERE a = b GROUP BY P"
    End With
    Dim objReader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While objReader.Read
        Chart2.Series("Stops").Points.AddXY(objReader("lines").ToString, objReader("SUM").ToString)
    End While
Catch ex As Exception
    If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox(ex.InnerException)
    End If
End Try
DisconnectDatabase()
```

The MySQL query is correct, and i can see the X axis correctly, but in the Y axis nothing appears, and it doesn't plot anything.
Can you please help? What am i doing wrong?

There's a print of how SUM looks like:
[image]

Thanks.

UPDATE: Problem solved. In the select query i just select the data in Hours.

Comment: Would it be possible to see the structure of the query result? I'm just wondering if because SUM is a keyword if that is throwing up an issue. A quick test would be to change that to something other than SUM and fix the series argument to reflect the change.

Comment: I made a test and changed the axis, i mean, i putted SUM in the X axis and the lines in the Y axis.
The SUM appears and the name lines no. So the problem need to be in the Y axis but i'm not figuring out why...

Comment: so a typical SUM result would be something like '110:43:00h'? Because it's looking for a numerical value. If that represents 110 hours and 43 minutes you may need to get that into a number that represents it 110.72 which is 110.72 hours or 110 hours and 43/60 hours.

Comment: Check the image i put in the question.

Comment: OK, so what does a typical sum look like? (The value you're passing into the y axis) because that looks like you're trying to pass a non-numeric value to the y-axis.

Comment: Didn't get your point. Why can i show SUM in the X axis and not in the Y axis?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102260/discussion-between-charles-may-and-vallete7).

Comment: Click on the link in the last comment to continue this in the chat room.

Answer (score 0):

Make your y-values numeric instead of strings.

Change

```vb
Chart2.Series("Stops").Points.AddXY(objReader("lines").ToString, objReader("SUM").ToString)
```

to

```vb
Chart2.Series("Stops").Points.AddXY(objReader("lines").ToString, Double.Parse(objReader("SUM").ToString))
```

Comment: Check out this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624066/how-to-set-values-in-x-axis-mschart-using-c-sharp